# Is there any equivalent for \n?

Tags: java, newline, testlink

I am trying to import text in TestLink using the library [testlinkjavaapi](https://jar-download.com/java-documentation-javadoc.php?a=testlink-java-api&g=br.eti.kinoshita&v=1.9.0-1)  but the character `\n` does not seem to be understood by this api and all linebreaks are gone.

I changed all my `\n` character to the hexadecimal `0x0A` but to no avail.

Comment: I am not familiar with the library, but if HTML is involved, try `<br>, <br />, <p>`

Comment: For me **why the '/n' is not understood** is more serious problem.

Comment: `\n` and `0xa` are exactly the same thing. You might have been better off changing them to `\r\n`. Rather than accomplishing nothing.

Comment: When I inspect linebreaks directly in Testlink, they are represented as `<p> <\p>` but using this library, I have to send a String so I don't know if using HTML code will be efficient... I will try all of your solutions immediatly, thank you

Comment: I just tried all of your solution but none seems to be efficient... :(

Comment: @LauraG instead of `\n` have you tried`System.getProperty("line.separator")`?

Comment: Yes I did try it but no linebreak is visible in TestLink

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out how to solve the problem !
I used the `concat` method and add only `<br/>` to my lines.

Thank you all for your interest !